# Websockets. Tyrus. Time for which the client is connected to a socket

Tags: websocket, tyrus

How can I get time for which the client is connected to a socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature.

I'd suggest creating `@OnOpen` method, which will save the time to current instance (Endpoints are by default WebSocket Session scoped) and work with that value.

Feel free to [file an enhancement against Tyrus](https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS).